# Finding all available styles defined by android platform themes

Tags: android, themes, styles

In several android styling tutorials parent style elements are used that i can not find in the android.R.style.* styles (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html).

A few examples are from the http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html action bar article. Nick uses parent styles like:

```
<style name="MyDropDownNav" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
...
</style>
```

or

```
<style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBarView_TabView">
...
</style>
```

Where do these parent styles come from? Is it possible to list all available parent styles?

Thanks.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As stated in the ["Applying Styles and Themes"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles) article:

> The Android platform provides a large collection of styles and themes
>   that you can use in your applications. You can find a reference of all
>   available styles in the [R.style](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html) class. To use the styles listed here,
>   replace all underscores in the style name with a period. For example,
>   you can apply the [Theme_NoTitleBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_NoTitleBar) theme with 
>   **`"@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`**.
>
> The [R.style](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html) reference, however, is not well documented and does not
>   thoroughly describe the styles, so viewing the actual source code for
>   these styles and themes will give you a better understanding of what
>   style properties each one provides. For a better reference to the
>   Android styles and themes, see the following source code:
>
> - [Android Styles (styles.xml)](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml)
> - [Android Themes (themes.xml)](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml)
>
> These files will help you learn through example. For instance, in the
>   Android themes source code, you'll find a declaration for **`<style
>   name="Theme.Dialog">`**. In this definition, you'll see all of the
>   properties that are used to style dialogs that are used by the Android
>   framework.

Comment: would be good if someone can point to source of above files where i can browse just styles & themes without downloading whole source code of android

Comment: found the files at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/themes.xml?av=f

Answer (score 3):

For "android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBarView_TabView" see:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Widget_Holo_Light_ActionBar_TabView
...and note the API level it was introduced at!

For "android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar" try:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Widget_Holo_Light_DropDownItem_Spinner

The latter is just my best guess - I can't get the list to actually drop down.

Answer (score 3):

`Parent` attribute is a optional one while creating your own `themes` or `styles`.
Basically `parent` attributes are used for inheriting the styles which are already defined in the platform itself.

If we wish to inherit a `theme` or `style` and overwriting some features, we can use `parent` attribute.

Here's a link for the all [available platform defined `styles`.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html)

And one more tip :

If you want to inherit your own `style` that you created by yourself means follow this example to inherit.

```
    <style name="MyDropDownNav.Red">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is `Official Google's Documentation` for `Default List` of `Themes` and `Styles`
[Google Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles)

You can Find here in this documentation

- [Android Styles (styles.xml)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml)
- [Android Themes (themes.xml)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml)

I know the answer to above question finishes over here still giving way of implementation, as it will be helpful for novices..

**How to Implement them**

This is what i got from the `themes.xml`

```
<style name="Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Now `to implement` it in my project

I have to add the following line in my `Styles.xml` file

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```

In this I am creating my `own theme` named "`AppTheme`" which will `inherit` its properties from `already defined them by google`. so I am mentioning it in `parent`

By looking into `themes.xml` and `styles.xml` will not only `help to get the list of the already defined` themes and styles but also `help novices to have an idea how to create` the themes.

As the theme I am mentioning here in `parent` is already defined by android so we will use it by prefixing the `android:` to theme name ..

If You want to `inherit your created theme` then

```
<style name="Theme2" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

then just provide the `style name to the parent`, here i am using `Apptheme` as parent theme for `theme2`

Comment: nice not only the names it has but also the source codes of themes
although it is not very different from "Idolon" solution rather than its just pointing to different pages which belongs to google.