# Android - Missing Parent Theme?

Tags: android, xml, styles

I'm attempting to style the ActionBar, following this blog post:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

With this source code:

`svn checkout http://styled-action-bar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ styled-action-bar-read-only`

However, I'm getting issues in `/res/values/styles.xml`.

This:

```
<!-- style for the tabs -->
<style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBarView_TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_bg</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">32dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">32dp</item>
</style>
```

Is erroring with:

`Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBarView_TabView'.`

However, using the following answer, and digging through the source for Android, I can see that the theme does indeed exist:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7149389/420001

The only thing that I changed in the project was moving it from `android-11` to `android-14`, and then running an "Android" > "Fix Project Properties" in Eclipse. I do note that the repo linked to in that answer, that lists the style, is on branch master, so I can't see why the theme would be unfound.

Just for tests, I put that chunk of code in my working `android-14` targeting app, minus the background drawable, and it throws the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the links in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7837756/1003511 there is a `Widget_Holo_Light_ActionBar_TabView` but not a `Widget_Holo_Light_ActionBarView_TabView`. It's possible the resource has been renamed since that tutorial was written. It says the version without the extra "view" has been included since API level 13 - if the tutorial was originally written on 11 it's possible it was renamed in 13, and since you are running 14 you can only see the renamed version. I'd try removing the extraneous "view" and see if the code runs.

Comment: Bingo. `Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView` did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may be missing an '@' character when specifying that you want to look in the android styles:

You can also double check to see if the parent style is listed in the API documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html

It looks like you may have the name slightly wrong.