# How to extract the source code of Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar?

Tags: android, android-styles

How to extract or view the source code of Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar ? i need this for samsumg galaxy note 3, is their any way to see what customization was made in the device ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all available styles defined by android platform themes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562272/finding-all-available-styles-defined-by-android-platform-themes)

Comment: What are your reasons for doing this?

Comment: @Code-appentice: because on Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar my EditText is showing correctly copy past popup menu (not in the action bar) where on the other theme it's didn"t :( so i would like to know what is different in Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar. see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396662/edittext-how-to-activate-copy-paste-popup-without-any-actionbar

Comment: [Here's the source of that theme](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/e71ecb2c4df15f727f51a0e1b65459f071853e35/core/res/res/values/themes_device_defaults.xml#L457)

Comment: thanks cricket_007 ! but i think the source i need is specific to my device (samsung). here it's the generic source that point to theme.Material :(

Answer (score 0):

Basically the answer must be: **you can't**. 
The name of the style implies that it's device specific. Each individual device manufacturer decides about the content of this style.

Comment: yes but i would like to see on my particular device how it is configured. it's because on Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar my EditText is showing correctly copy past popup menu (not in the action bar) where on the other theme it's didn"t :(

Comment: I think you **can** view them, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to answer @loki I don't think the theme decides the Contextual Action Bar. Samsung devices may have their own, special pop-up menu, and for that, I'm not sure you can see the source

Comment: @cricket yes i think you are right ! but i can't understand how samsung does their own special pop-up menu ... after all it's just some style ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the one that one want, but it just links to the Material Light NoActionBar theme

```
<!-- Variant of {@link #Theme_DeviceDefault_Light} with no action bar -->
<style name="Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"  />
```

Which looks like this

```
<!-- Variant of the material (light) theme with no action bar. -->
<style name="Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

[Github Marshmallow MR2 - core/res/values](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/marshmallow-mr2-release/core/res/res/values)